# Only pom.xml retrieved from maven dependency in gradle spring boot project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This is for sure a duplicate question, but I am not understanding what's happening.

I am trying to use the apicurio-registry library.
I added the following line in my build.gradle file :

```
implementation group: 'io.apicurio', name: 'apicurio-registry', version: '1.3.1.Final', ext: 'pom'
```

After building, I can see that I only retrieved the pom.xml, but not any of the jars specified in it (There is nothing except the pom.xml in the gradle caches).

Comment: see if this is resolution for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575065/how-to-use-pom-type-dependency-in-gradle

Comment: Adding the transitive flag to true didn't change anything